# Stereochemistry & mechanism of β-cyano enone methylation

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, conformers, grignard-reagent, stereoselectivity

I am helping a friend with some upper-level mechanism problems. We came across this one. This is my proposal. Do you agree/disagree? Thank you for any input.
[image]

Source question:
[image]

Comment: In your mechanism, you have an anion next to a nitrile: that is good, but you should not draw it as a chair anymore, that carbon with a negative charge should be sp2, precisely because of the resonance stabilisation.

Comment: Fixing again... realizing it after you said that!

Comment: No problem. Now, the interesting part of the question IMO is the stereochemistry. The six-membered-ring-with-one-sp2-carbon should probably be drawn like cyclohexanone, and [there are stereochemical models for nucleophilic attack on cyclohexanones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cieplak_effect); problem is I don't know what extent this is relevant for electrophilic attack of MeI on the carbanion...

Comment: @orthocresol - my initial thought was the C=O was going to be most reactive to the Grignard, then anion would be better resonance-stabilized next to the nitrile than adding beta to that group.

Comment: Why would the Methyl Grignard attack the carbon on the double bond next to the nitrile in your 2nd step? This seems highly unlikely to me. It would be more likely to add to the other end of the double bond in a Michael attack on the nitrile

Comment: It should attack the carbon beta to the nitrile to produce the resonance-stabilized anion as I have shown. How can we rationalize this stereochemistry is where I am slightly perplexed.

Comment: In the source question, I understand why the beta 1,3 carbon would be attacked (most electropositive from ketone/nitrile), but it isn't mechanistically productive. If the ketone is attacked first, it isolates the beta position and allows the setup of the resonance-stabilized carbanion.

Comment: You shows in your second structure, Grignard attacking the $\alpha$ carbon to carbonyl (not carbonyl anymore though), yet you shows methyl on  the $\beta$ carbon to carbonyl  with negative charge making $\beta$ carbon pentavalent (with negative charge). This should be fixed ASAP.

Comment: @mathewmahindaratne - fixed; apologies for the error - didn't catch it previously

Comment: The first two structures in the third line are not related to the starting cyanoketone. The carbonyl  group is in the wrong position in the first structure.

Comment: The details are here: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jo052102j

Comment: @user55119: You are correct about the error. Also, the carbonyl group is in the wrong position not only in the first structure, but also in the second structure. Rest is okay.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent reference. I started to consider magnesium coordination  but debated it.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanism I developed from the paper @user55119 graciously provided. Appreciate it! Any refinements I appreciate. :)

[image]

Comment: One suggestion. Although the relative stereochemistry is what is important, try not to switch absolute stereochemistry as you have done in line 2. For the right hand structure in line 2, draw the same chair cyclohexane but shift all substituents one carbon to the left where axial becomes equatorial and equatorial becomes axial.